# Is there a point to playing the Tiny Death Star if I don't plan on spending any money?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've been playing Tiny Death Star on the iPad for 2 months now and it just gets repetitive: refill the products, find the occasional spy, collect some things from Imperial levels.  I've built up 40 retail levels plus 6 Imperial ones.

I suspect there is more to the game if you decided to spend real money to buy Imperial Bux, but I am not planning to.

Is there more to this game other than what I am already doing, given that I am not planning to spend any money on it?

Comment: Only you can answer this question for yourself.  Personally, I've given up on the game as boring.  But, this is a common state with video games.  They eventually get repetitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no difference to the content of TDS whether you spend any real money on it or not. Meaning, you are already enjoying the game's full features (until new updates come along).

The only difference for people who buy bux is that they have access to certain things much faster and much earlier (using bux to stock levels, build levels, summon salvage droids to get characters and levels, summon decorator droids etc). For people who don't buy bux, they enjoy the same features of the game but it's a much slower process as they have to save up bux.

Answer (score 1):

As Han has just stated, you can still play the game but it will definitely be a lot slower doing it for free, especially the probe droid quest which i've found next to impossible so far and i've spent a lot of real money buying bux and still not gotten any extra levels so far, and for time limited quests then it can be cutting it quite close as to whether you can complete it in time without spending real money on bux, totally up to you how you want to play it out.